# MySQL error Reatest-n-per-group

Tags: php, greatest-n-per-group

Help me!

```
       SELECT ma_forum.*, ma_forum_cat.*

        FROM ma_forum, ma_forum_cat

        JOIN ma_forum_comentarios ON ma_forum_comentarios.not_id = ma_forum.not_id

        GROUP BY ma_forum.not_id

        WHERE ma_forum.notcat_id=ma_forum_cat.notcat_id AND ma_forum.notcat_id='".$notcat_id."' 

        AND ma_forum.not_status='Ativo'

        ORDER BY MAX(ma_forum_comentarios.comnot_data) DESC
```

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ma_forum.notcat_id=ma_forum_cat.notcat_id AND ma_forum.notcat_id='1' ' at line 9"

Comment: GROUP BY is in the wrong place in your query. I think it comes after WHERE but before ORDER BY.

Comment: @andrewsi that should really be an answer

Comment: I didn't want to post an answer until I'd had a change to look up the right syntax. I can never remember whether GROUP BY or ORDER BY comes first.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is in the wrong order; GROUP BY should be after WHERE and before ORDER BY:

```
SELECT ma_forum.*, ma_forum_cat.*
FROM ma_forum, ma_forum_cat
JOIN ma_forum_comentarios ON ma_forum_comentarios.not_id = ma_forum.not_id
WHERE ma_forum.notcat_id=ma_forum_cat.notcat_id AND ma_forum.notcat_id='".$notcat_id."' 
AND ma_forum.not_status='Ativo'
GROUP BY ma_forum.not_id
ORDER BY MAX(ma_forum_comentarios.comnot_data) DESC
```

I don't know what database you're using, but here's a link to [MySQL's SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Yes! Gave another error now.

Unknown column 'ma_forum.not_id' in 'on clause'